# Is there any way to make JavaFX spinner repeat its value range when hitting the lowest/highest value?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, spinner

Is there any way to make JavaFX spinner repeat its value range when hitting the lowest/highest value?
For example, here I have Spinner with minValue 1, maxValue 5, initial value 3:

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(1, 5, 3);
```

What I need is that when I reach number 1 and press down arrow, number 5 shows up and when I press up arrow, number 1 shows up.

I was wondering about checking when are the arrows pressed and edit the value if needed, but I think there might be some property or some other, simpler way, which does this automatically, but couldn't find any.

Thank You very much.

Comment: Did you try to set the [wrap around](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/SpinnerValueFactory.html#wrapAroundProperty()) property to true?

Comment: @matt Thank You very much. I did't know there is an option to use ValueFactory on Spinner, so Your solution worked for me. JavaFX is still new for me and I have difficulties to understand some mechanisms of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think it is a good idea to sum this up and post the exact answer I needed.

To create JavaFX Spinner with wrap-around values, I had to do this:

```
SpinnerValueFactory<Integer> valueFactory = new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(1, 5, 3);
valueFactory.setWrapAround(true);
Spinner<Integer> spinner = new Spinner<>();
spinner.setValueFactory(valueFactory);
```